# Why does Sikuli fail to take pictures

Tags: sikuli

I have worked extensively with Robot Framework Selenium and Sikuli, but this is weird. My compnay puts stringent security in place that MAY has something to do with it. I am configuring a new system with RFW and sikuli. I finally have the tests running and it can't find an image. After reviewing the resoluiton again, I just ran the test to take a picture with sikuli. Maybe it isn't even getting the right VNC screen. So I capture the screen and get something like this. Its a semi-random RGB image. I'm never see anything like this.

My only thought is that it might be a resolution issue. I went below the 1290/720 limit, but maybe I need something specific. This is on a RHEL 8. Maybe that has some affect.

[image]

I already tried a few resolutions. No change worth noting.